# Match unescaped quotes in quoted csv

Tags: python, regex, csv, regex-lookarounds

I've looked at several of the Stack Overflow posts with similar titles, and none of the accepted answers have done the trick for me.

I have a CSV file where each "cell" of data is delimited by a comma and is quoted (including numbers). Each line ends with a new line character.

Some text "cells" have quotation marks in them, and I want to use regex to find these, so that I can escape them properly.

Example line:

```
"0","0.23432","234.232342","data here dsfsd hfsdf","3/1/2016",,"etc","E 60"","AD"8"\n
```

I want to match **just the `"`** in `E 60"` and in `AD"8`, but not any of the other `"`.

What is a (preferably Python-friendly) regular expression that I can use to do this?

Comment: ***https://regex101.com/r/VxEXf2/3***

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is close, but I want to match just those internal quote characters so that I can replace them (I don't want to replace the `E 60` part, for example. I think I also need the rest of the string to be a little more flexible than restricting to single numbers and letters in the other strings (see updated original post example).

Comment: Can you update the match you want as well

Comment: The match is the same -- just the internal `"` characters. I think this does it, though probably not as efficiently as possible: `r'(?<!^)(?<!,)\"(?!,|$)'`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qbPgxJ/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Updated with regex from @sundance to avoid beginning of line and newline.

You could try substituting only quotes that aren't next to a comma, start of line, or newline:

```
import re

newline = re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?<!,)"(?!,|$)', '', line)
```

Comment: Worked! I used `re.compile` to compile it first, and then the `sub` method on the compiled regex string. Was able to clean up my 4M line file in about 3-4 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using regex, here's an approach that uses Python's string functions to find and escape only quotes between the left and rightmost quotes of a string.

It uses the `.find()` and `.rfind()` methods of strings to find the surrounding `"` characters. It then does a replacement on any additional `"` characters that appear inside the outer quotes. Doing it this way makes no assumptions about where the surrounding quotes are between the `,` separators, so it will leave any surrounding whitespace unaltered (for example, it leaves the `'\n'` at the end of each line as-is).

```
def escape_internal_quotes(item):
    left = item.find('"') + 1
    right = item.rfind('"')
    if left < right:
        # only do the substitution if two surrounding quotes are found
        item = item[:left] + item[left:right].replace('"', '\\"') + item[right:]
    return item

line = '"0","0.23432","234.232342","data here dsfsd hfsdf","3/1/2016",,"etc","E 60"","AD"8"\n'
escaped = [escape_internal_quotes(item) for item in line.split(',')]
print(repr(','.join(escaped)))
```

Resulting in:

```
'"0","0.23432","234.232342","data here dsfsd hfsdf","3/1/2016",,"etc","E 60\\"","AD\\"8"\n'
```

Comment: This may get to the same answer, but it's bound to be less efficient than a regex engine. I need to do this on 4M lines, so performance would be an issue

Comment: @sundance Thanks for the feedback. I didn't realize how large your file was. I ran timings and find that the non-regex solution takes about twice as long (so roughly 8 minutes for your file).