# TCL Regex to match unescaped quotes in CSV

Tags: regex, csv, tcl, quotes

i've been through several Q&A here to address this problem with a CSV, i have.

Here's an example of a CSV with unescaped quotes at 5"-

`"522","-1","12345678","12345678","Completed","","","","height 5' 5" and weight 170lbs","","","9876543","ABCD","2016-06-12T23:54:00-05:00","2016-06-12T23:59:00-05:00"`

I've already used this suggestion from here : [Match unescaped quotes in quoted csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623701/match-unescaped-quotes-in-quoted-csv) and `(?<!^|",)"(?!,|$)` regex works beautifully, but in the PHP context.

My goal is to match a single double quote (") that's being quoted between double-quotes (") but in the TCL context. Any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: that's not well-formed CSV: the "inner" double quote should be doubled: `"height 5' 5"" and weight 170lbs"` -- https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 2):

Since the question you link to is about *removing* the "wild" double quotation marks inside CSV fields, all you need to do is to revamp the lookbehind into a capturing group with a negated bracket expression:

```
set a {"522","-1","12345678","12345678","Completed","","","","height 5' 5" and weight 170lbs","","","9876543","ABCD","2016-06-12T23:54:00-05:00","2016-06-12T23:59:00-05:00"}
set result [regsub -all {([^,])"(?=[^,])} $a "\\1"]
puts $result
```

See the [online Tcl demo](https://ideone.com/KxIynw), output:

```
"522","-1","12345678","12345678","Completed","","","","height 5' 5 and weight 170lbs","","","9876543","ABCD","2016-06-12T23:54:00-05:00","2016-06-12T23:59:00-05:00"
```

The `([^,])"(?=[^,])` regex matches

- `([^,])` - Group 1 (referred to later with `\1`): any char but `,`
- `"` - a double quote
- `(?=[^,])` - a positive lookahead that requires a char other than a comma to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to split instead, so you can also perform additional checks on your csv line. I would suggest something like the following with the help of the [default csv package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html#2):

```
package require csv

set input {"522","-1","12345678","12345678","Completed","","","","height 5' 5" and weight 170lbs","","","9876543","ABCD","2016-06-12T23:54:00-05:00","2016-06-12T23:59:00-05:00"}

# Quick check the line, if it's not complete...
if {![::csv::iscomplete $input]}    
    # Replace all 'quote comma quote' with null character (or some other character you are certain is 
    # not in your csv line
    set intermediate [regsub -all {","} $input \0]

    # Split on null character (or the character you picked on the previous line)
    set columns [split $intermediate \0]

    # Ensure that the csv line contains the expected number of columns
    if {[llength $columns] == 15} {
        # Replace the quotes in each element of the list of columns
        set columns [lmap x $columns {string map {{"} {}} $x}]
    } else {
        # Do further checks otherwise to see what's wrong
    }
    puts "Split data:"
    puts $columns        
} else {
    set columns [::csv::split -alternate $input]
}
set output [::csv::join $columns "," always]
puts "\nRejoined (if you still need it):"
puts $output
```

Outputs:

```
Split data:
522 -1 12345678 12345678 Completed {} {} {} {height 5' 5 and weight 170lbs} {} {} 9876543 ABCD 2016-06-12T23:54:00-05:00 2016-06-12T23:59:00-05:00

Rejoined (if you still need it):
"522","-1","12345678","12345678","Completed","","","","height 5' 5 and weight 170lbs","","","9876543","ABCD","2016-06-12T23:54:00-05:00","2016-06-12T23:59:00-05:00"
```

That way you have more control over what's happening and potentially finding any other issues with the csv.